# Löwenheim number of the logic $\mathrm{FOL}[L]$ ($(Lx)[\varphi,\psi]$ holds iff $|\{x:\varphi\}| \ge 2^{|\{x:\psi\}|}$)

Tags: logic, model-theory, higher-order-logic

**What is the Löwenheim number of the logic $\mathrm{FOL}[L]$?**

**Let $L$ be the quantifier with the intended reading *a lot more*, and the semantics shown at the end of this section. $D_1$ and $D_2$ are sorts. The variable introduced by $L$ can have different sorts in the left and right branches. $2^\square$ is the ordinal map $ \omega \mapsto 2^\omega$.**

**For the purposes of this question, I will treat the cardinals as a subclass of the ordinals.**

$$ (L x : (D_1, D_2))[\varphi(x), \psi(x)] \;\text{holds} \;\;\textit{if and only if}\;\; |\{x : \varphi(x)\}| \ge 2^{|\{x : \psi(x)\}|} $$

---

A [Löwenheim number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim_number) is defined as:

> the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that if an arbitrary sentence of [the logic] has any model, the sentence has a model of cardinality no greater than $\kappa$.

I'm interested in this quantifier because it can be used to define $\exists$ and thus $\forall$.

$$ (\exists x)[\varphi(x)] \;\; \text{can be defined as} \;\; (Lx)[\varphi(x), x \neq x] $$

I'm curious what the Löwenheim number of $\mathrm{FOL}[L]$ is.

Let $\varphi^0$ be a first-order axiom of infinity. $\varphi^0$ is also a $\mathrm{FOL}[L]$ sentence, therefore the Löwenheim number is at least $\beth_0$.

However, we can define $\varphi^1$ by introducing a new predicate symbol $R^1$. This shows that the Löwenheim number is at least $\beth_1$.

$$ \varphi^1 \;\;\text{is defined as}\;\; (Lx)[R^1(x), \varphi^0(x)] $$

And we can define $\varphi^{(n+1)}$ as follows.

$$ \varphi^{(n+1)} \;\;\text{is defined as}\;\; (Lx)[R^{(n+1)}(x), \varphi^{n}(x)] $$

I think this proves that the Löwenheim number of this logic is at least $\beth_\omega$, but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure how much higher the true Löwenheim number of $\mathrm{FOL}[L]$ is (assuming my argument is correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the Lowenheim number of this logic, which I'll call "$\lambda$," is at least $\beth_\omega$. However, $\lambda$ is in fact much larger than $\beth_\omega$, due to the power which *parameters* bring into the new quantifier $\mathsf{L}$.

Roughly speaking, suppose I have a pair of binary relation symbols $R, S$. Then in $\mathsf{FOL[L]}$ I can write a sentence $\theta$ saying the following:

- $R$ is a linear order;
- whenever $R(x,y)$ we have $\mathsf{L} z(S(y,z),S(x,z))$.

Basically, this says that $R$ and $S$ together describe a sequence of sets which increase rapidly in size. Building off of this we can for example write a satisfiable sentence $\beta$ whose smallest model has cardinality $\min\{\alpha:\beth_\alpha=\alpha\}$, the least "$\beth$ fixed point," which is much bigger than $\beth_\omega$ (it's the limit of the sequence $\beth_\omega,\beth_{\beth_\omega},\beth_{\beth_{\beth_\omega}}$, ...): basically, say add to the above sentence a clause saying that the domain of $R$ is the whole universe. Note that if we drop the exponential aspect of $2^-$, we'll still get a rather large lower bound on the Lowenheim number, namely the least $\aleph$ fixed point.

(As a cute aside, note that there is no infinite sequence of sets $(A_i)_{i\in\omega}$ such that $2^{\vert A_{i+1}\vert}<\vert A_i\vert$. This means that the $\theta$-trick above also lets us restrict attention to well-orderings in a way quite beyond the capacity of first-order logic alone. Note that the nonexistence fact two sentences prior does *not* rely on the axiom of choice as long as we use the exponential version of $\mathsf{L}$; this is a good exercise, and falls e.g. out of the proof of the existence of Hartogs numbers.)

Comment: Thank you. Is the $x$ argument of $R(x, y)$ larger than the $y$ argument or vice versa? It looks to me like the left argument is bigger by the $(Lz)[S(x, z), S(y, z)]$ axiom. I also don't really understand what role $S$ is playing here.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet The idea is that $S$ "attaches" a set $X_a$ of elements to each element $a$ in the field of $R$ (namely $X_a=\{b: S(a,b)\}$), and the $R$-ordering forces the size of $X_a$ to strictly increase as $a$ increases along $R$. (You're right about the variable order, though; it's not a serious issue but it does affect readability/intuitiveness, so I've changed it.)

Comment: Ah okay. I think I get it now. For some reason I was thinking of the variables in your example as denoting "set-like things" with $R$ being analogous to $\subset$. That's not what's happening; rather $S^\leftarrow(a_1), S^\leftarrow(a_2) \cdots$ where $i \le j \to (i, j) \in R$ is our sequence of sets and then on top of that we do something to make the domain of $R$ sufficiently big to force our model to be large.

Comment: One thing confuses me about the exercise at the end. $A'' = \{ \beth_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a set, right? Then $A = \{ \beth_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ would also be a set by specification or replacement, and would (when interpreted as a sequence) also satisfy $2^{|A_{i+1}|} < |A_i|$ ... unless there's something I'm missing. (If I am misinterpreting the exercise (which seems likely), I would like a hint since I'm going to try to prove it later.)

Comment: @GregNisbet Check your subscripts: your proposed sequence satisfies $\vert A_{i+1}\vert>2^{\vert A_i\vert}$. I'm saying that there is no **powerset-*decreasing*** sequence (this is trivial in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and more interesting in $\mathsf{ZF}$).

Comment: Oh ... wait... the sets *would be* rapidly shrinking? So this is some kind of foundation-like property? Interesting.

Comment: @GregNisbet Well, they **can't** be, that's the point! It turns out that while $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent with the existence of a decreasing sequence of cardinalities (as long as we use the right definition of "cardinality"), this stronger notion of a "powerset-decreasing sequence" is outright disprovable.